# How to find out all the skos:broader relations from DBpedia in order to build the concept hierarchy (tree) by using SPARQL query

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper, skos

As I am using this query text to find out those skos:broader related concepts of the keyword: England.

```
select ?ChildNodes where 
{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> skos:broader ?ChildNodes
}
```

and I've got the result like this:

```
ChildNodes
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Germanic_countries_and_territories
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Great_Britain
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Island_countries
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Wikipedia_categories_named_after_countries
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:United_Kingdom_by_country
```

In order to build the concept hierarchy (tree), it is necessary for me to find out all the skos:broader relations of the result. Can any one let me know how to combine those SPARQL queries in one query? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I query through: http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: what is missing here? This are all direct relations, the result is correct

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
As I would like to find out all the skos:broader relations of the result.
For example, the skos:broader relations of Germanic_countries_and_territories, Great_Britain, Island_countries, Wikipedia_categories_named_after_countries and United_Kingdom_by_country. 
How can I combine those SPARQL queries in one query? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: what means "all"? There are just five or not? if you mean the transitive ones, do `skos:broader*`

Comment: "All" means all of five skos:broader relations of the result.

Comment: For example, I firstly use this query text to find out those skos:broader related concepts of the keyword: England.

`select ?ChildNodes where { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> skos:broader ?ChildNodes }
`
Then, from the result, I would like to find out the skos:broader relations of Germanic_countries_and_territories. I will use this query text:
`select ?GrandchildNodes where 
{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> skos:broader ?GrandchildNodes }
`
The problem is how can I combine them into one query. Hope that it is easy for you to understand.

Comment: you can use `UNION` for example: `select * where { {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> skos:broader ?ChildNodes
} UNION {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> skos:broader/skos:broader ?GrandchildNodes}}` - not sure if this is what you want

Comment: Thank you so much! It is exactly what I am looking for. I will keep trying to familiar with the sparql query.

Comment: I got a little bit confused that what is the meaning of `skos:broader/skos:broader`. Is it same as skos:broader?

Comment: It's just a path of length 2 of two `skos:broader` egdes

Comment: Thank you so much @UninformedUser . I still got some questions that you may help.
When I query for the skos:narrower relation, for example, `select ?ParentNodes where { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> skos:narrower ?ParentNodes }`,the result is empty. However, I look at the skos:concept of England [link]http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:England , the property:"is skos:broader of" does exist. isn't it means skos:narrower relation? Thank you so much!

Comment: no, it does not. The property to use is still `skos:broader`. "is <property> of" in DBpedia web view of a resource means, subject and object position are switched. That means the RDF triple in the dataset is `o skos:broader s` when looking at the web page of `s`. In your case, `select ?childNodes where { ?childNodes skos:broader <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> }` would do the trick. Indeed, I understand your reasoning, `skos:narrower` is indeed the inverse of `skos:broader`. But this needs a reasoner behind which is not the case in Virtuoso with out enabling some ruleset.

Comment: Thanks again for the immediately reply. Your answer is very easy to understand. is that means the skos:concept of Endland does not exist any skos:narrower relation? If it exist any skos:narrower relation with other concept, how can I find them out? Can you let me know more about the "reasoner"? Thank you so much

Comment: there is no need for a `skos:narrower` relation here is it is defined is the inverse of `skos:broader`. Obviously, adding both to the dataset would be redundant and double the size of the triples. A reasoner does make use of schema information, for Virtuoso as backend triple store of Dbpedia, it would need to register such a rule, which is not possible for you.

Comment: Just do `select ?childNodes where { ?childNodes skos:broader <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> }` and you'll get what you need. Or do `select ?childNodes where { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> skos:broader^ ?childNodes }` which is a SPARQL property path in inverse direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable advise. As I am going to build the concept hierarchy (tree) by using SPARQL query. Now, I am able to build some concept tree will semantic broader relations. For some concept which does no exist skos:broader relation,  the inverse of skos:broader relations may help the concept map building. For next stage, I am going to write the query for the automatically SPARQL query against one keyword. Do you think which is achievable? I am willing to hearing from you. Thank you so much!! speechless!

Comment: @UninformedUser - Note that your `select ?childNodes where { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> skos:broader^ ?childNodes }` is incorrect -- the carat (`^`) must precede the property to invert it; i.e., `skos:broader^` should be `^skos:broader`. BBQ - You may benefit by reviewing the [SPARQL 1.1 Property Path documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths).

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggesetion! @TallTed

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to find the broader concepts for each of the five results in the resultset. If this is the case, your query should be like this:

```
SELECT ?ChildNodes ?ChildBroader WHERE {
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> skos:broader ?ChildNodes .
   ?ChildNodes skos:broader ?ChildBroader .
}
```

Furthermore, by using [SPARQL property paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/) you can traverse the graph at an arbitrary level.